# How to keep adb from connecting to a network device

Tags: adb, macos

When I run `adb devices` on my MacBook Pro running OS X 10.14.6, I see not only my phone connected by USB but also a network device that I have no interest in. This forces me to manually specify which device I mean when using adb and Android Studio (which I sometimes forget to do). Is there any way to prevent `adb` from connecting to network devices?

FWIW, here's what I see at the shell (with some digits of my first device's serial number obscured):

```
$ adb devices
List of devices attached
HT8531AXXXXX    device
192.168.86.223:5555 device
```

**Update**: I was able to temporarily get the network device to go away by running `adb disconnect`, as suggested in an answer, but it keeps reappearing.

Comment: AFAIK, ADB doesn't automatically connect to network devices (i.e. [the user has to manually call `adb connect`](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb#wireless)). Probably there's something from your side (3rd party apps on the PC, like screen mirroring, etc?) that is trying to initiate `adb connect` automatically?

Comment: I have the same problem with Nvidia Shield. Have you fixed that?

Comment: @MateuszKaflowski It hasn't reappeared lately.

Answer (score 2):

The listed device `192.168.86.223:5555 device` belongs to an device that has sometime been connected to your PC. adb saves this info until you manually disconnect this device.

To get rid of the entry execute the command

```
adb disconnect
```

Comment: Thanks, but it disappears only temporarily after I execute `adb disconnect`. Do you know how to make it go away permanently?

Comment: @EllenSpertus Then most likely you have some software installed that automatically recreates this entry. Check the programs you have installed, especially those that execute automatically on start-up or when a device is connected. What OS do you use?

Comment: OS X. I'll update the question.